# SELECT no rows and no columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, turing-complete

Is it possible to write a SELECT statement, which returns dataset with zero rows and zero columns?

Comment: No, a SELECT returns at least 1 column.

Comment: Perhaps this question could be made to seem useful if you explained the `turing-complete` tag.

Comment: I can't imagine any situation where a resultset with no columns could ever be useful for anything: it's hard to imagine what it would even *mean*, except that you've not queried for anything... in which case, what is it that you have done?

Comment: @eggyal It would be one less special case to worry about when autogenerating queries. Otherwise you might be inclined to just unconditionally include a `NULL` column all the time.

Comment: @binki: but such an auto-generated query is necessarily erroneous, so having an error thrown is more correct than burying it with a valid result by virtue of adding superfluous columns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A dataset will always have at least 1 column, even if it contains no data.

```
SELECT NULL;
```

EDIT:

As pointed out by @eggyal , above syntax will return a null row.

His query `select null from dual where false;` wont return a row.

Comment: This still has 1 row, too—[`select null from dual where false;`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/70867/0) would still contain a single column, but no rows.

Comment: FYI, `dual` can be used as a dummy table if (as here) no tables need be referenced.

Comment: @eggyal `dual` is an elegant solution, more concise than the one I gave, where it works, but it's not universally supported. It works in Oracle and MySQL (at least some versions?) but not in postgres.

Comment: @cazort: to be fair, the question was tagged [tag:mysql]… but of course it’s always helpful to have portable answers too!

Answer (score 1):

Not possible in my opinion. You will get at least one column, but no rows.

```
Select null from yourTable where 1 = 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for postgresql:

```
create table test22 ();
select * from test22;
```

Comment: I wonder if there is any way to modify your solution to where permanently creating a table is not necessary?

Comment: Make it a temporary table?

Answer (score 0):

it's normally used for Creating empty Table from an Existing Table

```
CREATE TABLE NEW_TABLE_NAME AS
  SELECT * 
  FROM EXISTING_TABLE_NAME
  where 1=2
```

Answer (score 0):

No, but it is possible to return a query with no rows. In order to do this without referencing any tables, you can use a subquery:

```
SELECT NULL FROM (SELECT NULL) AS temp WHERE false;
```

This query will have one (empty) column, but no rows.

I've used the above construct when there is a query that is different in different cases, followed by a code loop that iterates through the results, and under some conditions you want to make it skip the loop. Replacing the query with the one above is a way of returning empty results and thus skipping the loop without an `if` block. Because the query contains no table names, that aspect of the code never needs to be changed, and for this reason I prefer it to adding a condition like `WHERE false` in an existing query.

I prefer this solution to the more concise one referencing `dual` because that construct is not supported in PostgreSQL; this solution works with any backend that supports subqueries.